# Name of the notion dual to disjoint union? ("Exhaustive intersection"?)

Tags: elementary-set-theory, reference-request, terminology, boolean-algebra, lattice-orders

> **Question:** Given a set $X$ and subsets $S_1, S_2 \subseteq X$, what is $S_1 \cap S_2$ called when $S_1 \cup S_2 = X$?
>
> More generally, given a set $X$ and subsets $\{S_{i}\}_{i \in \mathcal{I}}$, with $S_{i_1} \cup S_{i_2} = X$ whenever $i_1 \not= i_2$, what is $\bigcap_{i \in \mathcal{I}} S_i$ called?

If there is no general terminology specific to power sets, then what about for general Boolean or bounded lattices?

**Note:** To be accepted, answers should ideally include at least one reference using the term. (Multiple references, or a standard textbook, would be fantastic however.) I've thought of possible ad hoc names myself (e.g. "codisjoint intersection" or "(pairwise) exhaustive intersection"), but I am asking here about whether standard terminology exists.

**Context:** Note that $S_1 \cup S_2 = X$ if and only if $S_1^c \cap S_2^c = \emptyset$ and that $(S_1 \cap S_2)^c = S_1^c \cup S_2^c$. So basically I am asking for the name of an intersection when the complement of the intersection is a disjoint union (of the complements).

From an order-theoretic perspective, $^c$ takes the original poset-lattice of subset inclusion of $X$ to its dual. So this notion is (order-theoretically) dual to the notion of disjoint union. Using typical notation for a [bounded lattice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lattice_(order)#Bounded_lattice), a disjoint union corresponds to the join $a_1 \lor a_2$ of two elements whose meet is the least element, $a_1 \land a_2 = 0$, whereas I am asking for the name of the dual notion, the *meet* $b_1 \land b_2$ of two elements whose join is the *greatest* element, $b_1 \lor b_2 = 1$.

I feel as if I've seen this notion used implicitly in the literature before, but it's pretty simple, so I don't recall it being given a name in the sources I've seen.

**Possibly related questions:**
[Why is it obvious that if the intersection of all sets is empty then its complements cover the whole space?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2729431/why-is-it-obvious-that-if-the-intersection-of-all-sets-is-empty-then-its-complem)
Technically this about jointly exhaustive sets rather than pairwise exhaustive sets, plus it's not asking about terminology.

[Name for collection of sets whose intersection is empty but where sets are not necessarily pairwise disjoint](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/451520/name-for-collection-of-sets-whose-intersection-is-empty-but-where-sets-are-not-n/4201740#4201740)
Again this answer is talking about the jointly exhaustive case, rather than pairwise exhaustive, plus it's not asking about terminology either.